# this code is from Python 3.4.1 Documentation but this fail,why?

Tags: python-3.x

this code is in Python3.4.1 Documentation>Tutorial>9. Classes>9.3.2. Class Objects 
I use python 3.4.1 but when I write this code in python shell and run this code,It fail,who knows why?

```
>>>class Complex:
       def _init_(self,realpart,imagpart):
       self.r=realpart
       self.i=imagpart

>>>x=Complex(3.0,-4.5)
>>>x.r,x.i
(3.0,-4.5)
```

Comment: You defined `_init_()` instead of `__init__()` (2 underscores instead of 1). And assuming that was your actual indentation, `self.r=realpart` and `self.i=imagpart` needs an extra tab before them because indentation is Python's way of keeping track of scope. By indenting an extra level, you're putting those two lines into the scope of the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Complex:
   def __init__(self,realpart,imagpart):
       self.r=realpart
       self.i=imagpart
```

In Python, whitespace *is* important, you have to indent correctly for the code to work. Also notice that there are *two* underscores before and after the `init` method's name - you should use a good IDE and/or text editor to avoid this kind of problems. Now this will work:

```
x=Complex(3.0,-4.5)
x.r,x.i
=> (3.0,-4.5)
```